# Remove Prefix In MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, prefix

at first i have this code in adding prefix:

```
Dim sSQL As String
sSQL = ("UPDATE `" + cboJob.Text + "` SET `Line Number` = CONCAT('a',`Line Number`) WHERE `Line Number` LIKE '%-%'")
MyDB.ExecQuery(sSQL, "wellsfargo")
```

and now my problem is how can I remove the prefix that I add awhile ago which is the 'a'

Answer (score 5):

```
 UPDATE your_table
 SET `Line Number` = substring(`Line Number`, 2)
 WHERE `Line Number` LIKE 'a%-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
Dim sSQL As String
sSQL = ("UPDATE `" + cboJob.Text + "` SET `Line Number` = `Line Number` WHERE `Line Number` LIKE '%-%'")
MyDB.ExecQuery(sSQL, "wellsfargo")
```

I have removed the CONCAT which prefixed the 'a' onto Line Number

Comment: Sorry; misunderstood the question - juergen d has posted a good answer.